# Is there a Python equivalent to PHPs loadXML()?

Tags: python

In PHP, I can use:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
@$doc->loadXML($htmlData);
```

to convert a string of HTML data to a DOM document object. Is there an equivalent way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the standard library:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: Will that parse HTML into XML, or is it just for reading an XML string or document into a DOM object?

Comment: ElementTree is for loading XML. It does not parse malformed XML. I'm unfamiliar with the details of PHP's `loadXML`, but if it tries to do something with arbitrary HTML that is not also valid XML, then that's something different and ElementTree won't do that. Instead, try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).